# Manager -> Employee association one level in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations, rails-models

I want to create manager->employee association.

- Manager have many employees
- Employee belongs to only one manager
- Manager does not have another manager

How to implement this design ? 
I created something closer(code is below) but in my design manager can have other manager.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "manager_id"
end
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How do you know who is a manager and who isn't? Do you have an attribute to mark an user as manager? Or is a user a manager if it has at least one employee? (In this last case you can't have managers without any employees.)

Comment: @3limin4t0r The user is manager until `manager_id` is `nil`, or I can add if need one more boolean attribute for manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a really standard self-joining setup (with a few small issues). You can limit the depth of the tree by just adding a custom validation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # optional: true is needed in Rails 5+ since belongs_to is no
  # longer optional by default
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User',
                       optional: true
  # pay attention to pluralization
  has_many :employees, class_name: 'User',
                       foreign_key: 'manager_id'
  # calls the custom validation we will define later
  validate :manager_must_be_a_manager, unless: :manager?

  def manager?
    manager.nil?
  end

  private
    # our custom validation method
    def manager_must_be_a_manager
      errors.add(:manager, 'is not a manager') unless manager.manager?
    end
end
```

So now if we run:

```
user_1 = User.create!
user_2 = User.create!(manager: user_1)
User.create!(manager: user_2)
```

The third line will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Manager is not a manager`.

Comment: There are some edge cases to be aware of though. Like if you do `u = User.new(manager: user_1); u.employees.new; u.save!"` it won't raise an error. It just doesn't persist the employee.

Comment: how to restrict that edge case ?

Comment: You could use an association callback that raises an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have one more field `manager: boolean` in your table. On the basis of this field you can decide whether a user is manager or not. Also you can add validations that manager_id must be blank if manager field is true.

```
validate :manager_id_blank_for_manager

has_many :employees, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "manager_id", dependent: :restrict_with_exception

scope :managers, ->{ where(manager: true) }

def manager?
  manager
end

private

def manager_id_blank_for_manager
  if manager_id.present? && manager?
    errors.add(:manager_id, :must_be_blank_for_manager) # Move this error to yml file
  end
end
```